# How to nest GeoJSON features based on their geometry in javascript?

Tags: javascript, geojson, d3

I have a GeoJson object with polygon features. Some of them have same geometry. 
They look like this:

```
squareData = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 2196272, "acq_date": "2014\/08\/29", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -179.5, -18.5 ], [ -178.5, -18.5 ], [ -178.5, -17.5 ], [ -179.5, -17.5 ], [ -179.5, -18.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 2492600, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/09", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 2446209, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/18", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 1562738, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/25", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 476723, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/27", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
...
] 
}
```

I want to nest them based on geometry values, to get an object like this one:

```
nestedData = [
{
  "key": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] },
  "values": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 2492600, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/09", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 2446209, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/18", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 1562738, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/25", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 476723, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/27", "firenum": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ] } }
] },
{ "key": ..., "values": [...] },
...
]
```

I've nested this data by acq_date property using d3.nest() function, but it doesn't seem to work on geometry property. Every geometry is considered an "Object", so I'm getting all features inside the first array element. I'm doing it in browser, so I need a solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question properly. If so,  could you expand on it a bit

Comment: Sorry, just got notified. The answer is great, thanks. So the key can only be a string? I'm going to search in this array by key comparing given polygon geometry. So I have to stringify my geometry to do a search?

Comment: No. The stringify was just to show the results. The main point is that you have to access the coordinates property of geometry in order to be able to nest on the coordinates rather than nesting on geometry directly.

Comment: Yep, but the key of a new nested array is a string, rather than the array. So I'll have to stringify coordinates to do a filter on nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the `geometry.coordinates` of the data object (d). So, given, something looking like this, ie, referencing the features array directly from you original featureCollection for brevity (ie, equivalent to squareData.features):

```
var features =  [
 { "type": "Feature", "properties": 
      { "gid": 2196272, "acq_date": "2014\/08\/29", "firenum": "1" },    
       "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -179.5, -18.5 ],
            [ -178.5, -18.5 ], [ -178.5, -17.5 ], [ -179.5, -17.5 ], [ -179.5, -18.5 ] ] ] 
  } 
},
 { "type": "Feature", "properties": 
     { "gid": 2492600, "acq_date": "2014\/07\/09", "firenum": "1" },
      "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -164.5, 54.5 ],
            [ -163.5, 54.5 ], [ -163.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 55.5 ], [ -164.5, 54.5 ] ] ]
     } 
   }
];
```

You can write something like:

```
 var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.geometry.coordinates})
    .entries(features);

 console.log(JSON.stringify(nest, null, 2));
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuxwLvxs/), which is clearly showing a group with multiple entries for the Polygon starting with the point [-164.5, 54.5]. The pretty print comes from the 3rd parameter to [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) and attaching it to an HTML pre element.

To use with your original `FeatureCollection`, just reference squareFeatures.features in the entries function.